# filtering word digit from number and blocking them

Tags: php, regex

I have  written regex to filter the number from text. Now if number contains word digit(exploit that I have to consider) then it should be encountered as digit and blocked.

Like if text contains number : 4534six56433 then final return value should be ************. Entire number being blocked considering six as `6`.

Below code has issue that it converts `six` to `6` and then number is blocked. But here it should not be converted to 6 and `six` should be converted to `***` in final matched result.

If in `$text= str_replace($v,array_search($v,$arrwords),$text);` if I convert six to `six` then issue is that it will not be matched by regex.

Is there any suggestion or hint for this?

Again let me clear: 456-six-45443-one-1

should be    :             `***_***_*****_***_*` ignore underscore

not like          : `***_*_*****_*_1` (what is happening in belove code which take `six` as 6 and block it)

```
function transform($text, $words)
{
    $arrwords = array(0=>'zero',1=>'one',2=>'two',3=>'three',4=>'four',5=>'five',6=>'six',7=>'seven',8=>'eight',9=>'nine');
    preg_match_all('/[A-za-z]+/', $text, $matches);
    $arr=$matches[0];
    foreach($arr as $v)
    {
        $v = strtolower($v);
        if(in_array($v,$arrwords))
        {
            $text= str_replace($v,array_search($v,$arrwords),$text);
        }
    }
    $resultSet = array();
    foreach ($words as $word){
        $pattern = '/^\(?(?:(?:0(?:0|11)\)?[\s-]?\(?|\+)44\)?[\s-]?\(?(?:0\)?[\s-]?\(?)?|0)(?:\d{2}\)?[\s-]?\d{4}[\s-]?\d{4}|\d{3}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3,4}|\d{4}\)?[\s-]?(?:\d{5}|\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3})|\d{5}\)?[\s-]?\d{4,5}|8(?:00[\s-]?11[\s-]?11|45[\s-]?46[\s-]?4\d))(?:(?:[\s-]?(?:x|ext\.?\s?|\#)\d+)?)$^|^2(?:0[01378]|3[0189]|4[017]|8[0-46-9]|9[012])\d{7}|1(?:(?:1(?:3[0-48]|[46][0-4]|5[012789]|7[0-49]|8[01349])|21[0-7]|31[0-8]|[459]1\d|61[0-46-9]))\d{6}|1(?:2(?:0[024-9]|2[3-9]|3[3-79]|4[1-689]|[58][02-9]|6[0-4789]|7[013-9]|9\d)|3(?:0\d|[25][02-9]|3[02-579]|[468][0-46-9]|7[1235679]|9[24578])|4(?:0[03-9]|2[02-5789]|[37]\d|4[02-69]|5[0-8]|[69][0-79]|8[0-5789])|5(?:0[1235-9]|2[024-9]|3[0145689]|4[02-9]|5[03-9]|6\d|7[0-35-9]|8[0-468]|9[0-5789])|6(?:0[034689]|2[0-689]|[38][013-9]|4[1-467]|5[0-69]|6[13-9]|7[0-8]|9[0124578])|7(?:0[0246-9]|2\d|3[023678]|4[03-9]|5[0-46-9]|6[013-9]|7[0-35-9]|8[024-9]|9[02-9])|8(?:0[35-9]|2[1-5789]|3[02-578]|4[0-578]|5[124-9]|6[2-69]|7\d|8[02-9]|9[02569])|9(?:0[02-589]|2[02-689]|3[1-5789]|4[2-9]|5[0-579]|6[234789]|7[0124578]|8\d|9[2-57]))\d{6}|1(?:2(?:0(?:46[1-4]|87[2-9])|545[1-79]|76(?:2\d|3[1-8]|6[1-6])|9(?:7(?:2[0-4]|3[2-5])|8(?:2[2-8]|7[0-4789]|8[345])))|3(?:638[2-5]|647[23]|8(?:47[04-9]|64[015789]))|4(?:044[1-7]|20(?:2[23]|8\d)|6(?:0(?:30|5[2-57]|6[1-8]|7[2-8])|140)|8(?:052|87[123]))|5(?:24(?:3[2-79]|6\d)|276\d|6(?:26[06-9]|686))|6(?:06(?:4\d|7[4-79])|295[567]|35[34]\d|47(?:24|61)|59(?:5[08]|6[67]|74)|955[0-4])|7(?:26(?:6[13-9]|7[0-7])|442\d|50(?:2[0-3]|[3-68]2|76))|8(?:27[56]\d|37(?:5[2-5]|8[239])|84(?:3[2-58]))|9(?:0(?:0(?:6[1-8]|85)|52\d)|3583|4(?:66[1-8]|9(?:2[01]|81))|63(?:23|3[1-4])|9561))\d{3}|176888[234678]\d{2}|16977[23]\d{3}|7(?:[1-4]\d\d|5(?:0[0-8]|[13-9]\d|2[0-35-9])|624|7(?:0[1-9]|[1-7]\d|8[02-9]|9[0-689])|8(?:[014-9]\d|[23][0-8])|9(?:[04-9]\d|1[02-9]|2[0-35-9]|3[0-689]))\d{6}|76(?:0[012]|2[356]|4[0134]|5[49]|6[0-369]|77|81|9[39])\d{6}|80(?:0\d{6,7}|8\d{7})|500\d{6}|(?:87[123]|9(?:[01]\d|8[0-3]))\d{7}|8(?:4[2-5]|70)\d{7}|70\d{8}|56\d{8}|(?:3[0347]|55)\d{8}|8(?:001111|45464\d)$|(?:\((\+?\d+)?\)|(\+\d{0,3}))? ?\d{2,3}([-\.]?\d{2,3} ?){3,4}/';
        preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );
        $this->pushToResultSet($matches);
    }
    return $resultSet;
}
```

Comment: Could you convert (e.g.) "six" to "000", "zero" to "0000", "seven" to "00000"?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish. What is that humongous pattern in your `preg_match_all()` for? What is the **original problem you're trying to solve**?

Comment: @AdrianWragg: no, only in stars

Comment: @AmalMurali: main problem is filtering the number from text and blocking them. Even if the number is like `12three4` then it should be blocked to `********`

Comment: @user3449212 Once you've converted them to 00000 etc, if I'm reading your code correctly your regex would then convert them to "*****" as required.

Comment: @AdrianWragg: But there one issue, it filters all UK numbers considering length of uk area code and remaining digits. So if length exeed then trailing digits are showon unfiltered. like 4567456765345seven as **************even . I need help in improving regex to filter entire number and if not valid number then leave it

Comment: @user3449212 To clarify, you're filtering out phone numbers? So if I wanted to have a phone number displayed by your system I can simply prefix it with eleven zeros to work around your filter? *[for non-UK readers, UK numbers are - generally - a five-digit area code and a six-digital local number]*

Comment: Adrian: yes phone number. I guess you are talking about replacing word digit by `0` to get filter it out/